# Adding item to list using the Foursquare API

Tags: list, foursquare

By using Foursquare's API I'm trying to add a new venue to a list that I made. Currently I use the [this](https://api.foursquare.com/v2/lists/MY_USER_ID/tips/?venueid=4b3bb64ff964a520627925e3&oauth_token=XXXXXXXXX) call:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/lists/MY_USER_ID/tips/?venueid=4b3bb64ff964a520627925e3&oauth_token=XXXXXXXXX

Although the venueID is correct the output I do get is:

```
{

meta: {
    code: 400
    errorType: "param_error"
    errorDetail: "Value 4b3bb64ff964a520627925e3 is invalid for item id"
}
response: { }

}
```

What might cause this error?

Answer (score 0):

In order to add a venue to an existing list, you need to make a request to:

```
POST https://api.foursquare.com/v2/lists/LIST_ID/additem?venueId=4b3...&oauth_token=XXXX
```

Let me know if that request doesn't work for you

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar issue on a different API call. The fix for my issue was to include the HTTP header content type like this: `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`